# Constructing Cartesian product from SPARQL variable

Tags: sparql

I need some help starting with SPARQL:
I have some individuals (A, B, C). I want to state, that they are all the same. I’ve tried the following:

```
PREFIX : <http://test.com#> 
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
CONSTRUCT {
  ?p  owl:sameAs ?p
}
WHERE {
} VALUES (?p) {
  (:A)
  (:B)
  (:C)
}
```

The result is:

```
:B  owl:sameAs  :B .
:A  owl:sameAs  :A .
:C  owl:sameAs  :C .
```

What I would like to have is something like this:

```
:A owl:sameAs :B
:A owl:sameAs :C
:B owl:sameAs :A
:B owl:sameAs :C
:C owl:sameAs :A
:C owl:sameAs :B
```

Do you have any hints for me, how to do that?

Comment: something like this? `PREFIX : <http://test.com#> 
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
CONSTRUCT {
  ?o1  owl:sameAs ?o2
}
WHERE {
 VALUES ?o1 {:A :B :C} 
  VALUES ?o2 {:A :B :C} 
}` - and if you don't want `:A owl:sameAs :A` add a filter `FILTER(?o1 != ?o2)`

Comment: Thank you for that hint. I’ve tried it and it worked, but I still have some trouble understanding, why SPARQL behaves different, if I use two variables instead of one?
Another question arises, because in my real problem I’ll get A, B, C returned from a subquery. I’ve tried to bind the returned variable to another variable, to duplicate it. But it behaves just like in my posted example with only one variable.

Comment: what do you mean by "two variables"? the only important in SPARQL is "bindings", that's all - if you do `select ?a (?a as ?b) {}` you have still just a set of bindings being pairs `(x,x), (y,y), ...` which indeed just results in `x owl:sameAs x, ...` - a cartesian always needs disconnected bindings (technically not correct)

Comment: if you just repeat the subquery and return a different variable, it should work